# GoogleSheet API Error: FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 808

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I am trying to access google sheet apis, But First I am trying to generate access token using below code.

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

getAccessToken = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   const key = require('./credentials.json');
   const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    null
   );
   jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
     reject(err);
     return;
    }
    console.log("token===",tokens.access_token);
    resolve(tokens.access_token);
   });
  });
 };

getAccessToken();
```

But failed to authorize it at **jwtClient.authorize()**
and getting error as below:

```
C:\Google API\GoogleSheet UsingJWT\GoogleSheet UsingJWT>node index.js
(node:16820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 808
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Google API\GoogleSheet UsingJWT\GoogleSheet UsingJWT\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at onerror (C:\Google API\GoogleSheet UsingJWT\GoogleSheet UsingJWT\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:117:21)
    at callbackError (C:\Google API\GoogleSheet UsingJWT\GoogleSheet UsingJWT\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:136:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:16820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16820) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am not using any proxy also. I am not able understand actual issue.

**Please anyone can help me?**

Comment: Hi there! I have been studying your script, but I don't find any obvious malfunction. I understand that the issue originates in the authentication flow, in that case I strongly advise you to follow the [Node.js Sheets API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) and see if it helps. Especially the first half of the code where a working auth flow is shown. Please test it and come back and share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to generate an [OAuth 2.0 token flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) for your Sheets API Node.js script, but you are getting an error as a response. That error message describes how this issue originates in unhandled promises. To solve that situation, you should use [handled promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). One way to do so is to use the following example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), myFunction);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {
    client_secret,
    client_id,
    redirect_uris
  } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error(
        'Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function myFunction(auth) {
  // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

That script will reach your goals as described, you only have to remember to change the [scope](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) (if needed) and to update `myFunction`. Feel free to drop a comment if you need help with this approach.